# Numpy append and normal append

Tags: python, list, numpy, append, atom-editor

```
x = [[1,2],[2,3],[10,1],[10,10]]

def duplicatingRows(x, l):
    severity = x[l][1]
    if severity == 1 or severity == 2:
        for k in range(1,6):
            x.append(x[l])

for l in range(len(x)):
    duplicatingRows(x,l)

print(x)            

x = np.array([[1,2],[2,3],[10,1],[10,10]])

def duplicatingRows(x, l):
    severity = x[l][1]
    if severity == 1 or severity == 2:
        for k in range(1,6):
            x = np.append(x, x[l])

for l in range(len(x)):
    duplicatingRows(x,l)

print(x)
```

I would like it to print an array with extra appended rows. 
Giving out a list of `[[1, 2], [2, 3], [10, 1], [10, 10], [1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2], [10, 1], [10, 1], [10, 1], [10, 1], [10, 1]]`. Why does it not work? I tried different combinations with concatenate as well, but it didnt work.

Comment: Don't try to use np.append.  It isn't worth it.

Answer (score 1):

You have some bugs in your code. Here's a little bit improved, correct, and (partially) vectorized implementation of your code which prints your desired output.

Here we leverage [`numpy.tile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) for repeating the rows, followed by a reshape so that we can append it along axis 0, which is what is needed.

```
In [24]: x = np.array([[1,2],[2,3],[10,1],[10,10]]) 

         def duplicatingRows(x, l): 
             severity = x[l][1] 
             if severity == 1 or severity == 2:
                 # replaced your `for` loop
                 # 5 corresponds to `range(1, 6)`
                 reps = np.tile(x[l], 5).reshape(5, -1) 
                 x = np.append(x, reps, axis=0) 
             return x 

         for l in range(len(x)): 
             x = duplicatingRows(x,l) 

         print(x)
```

**Output**:

```
[[ 1  2]
 [ 2  3]
 [10  1]
 [10 10]
 [ 1  2]
 [ 1  2]
 [ 1  2]
 [ 1  2]
 [ 1  2]
 [10  1]
 [10  1]
 [10  1]
 [10  1]
 [10  1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a whole-array approach

```
In [140]: arr = np.array([[1,2],[2,3],[10,1],[10,10]])
In [141]: arr
Out[141]: 
array([[ 1,  2],
       [ 2,  3],
       [10,  1],
       [10, 10]])
```

We want to replicate the rows where the 2nd column has a 1 or 2, right?  `isin` makes a nice 'mask' (we could also use `==` and `any`):

```
In [142]: np.isin(arr[:,1],[1,2])
Out[142]: array([ True, False,  True, False])
In [143]: torepeat = arr[np.isin(arr[:,1],[1,2])]
In [144]: torepeat
Out[144]: 
array([[ 1,  2],
       [10,  1]])
```

`np.repeat` does a nice job of replicating the values, which we can simply concatenate with the original:

```
In [145]: repeated = np.repeat(torepeat,5, axis=0)
In [146]: np.concatenate((arr, repeated),axis=0)
Out[146]: 
array([[ 1,  2],
       [ 2,  3],
       [10,  1],
       [10, 10],
       [ 1,  2],
       [ 1,  2],
       [ 1,  2],
       [ 1,  2],
       [ 1,  2],
       [10,  1],
       [10,  1],
       [10,  1],
       [10,  1],
       [10,  1]])
```

`np.append` uses `concatenate`.  It works ok with adding a single element to a 1d array, but becomes trickier to use with higher dimensions.  It's a poor imitation of the list append.  Also repeated concatenates in a loop is relatively slow.  We usually recommend list appends, with a single array build at the end.

Another way to use `repeat` iteratively:

```
In [164]: np.concatenate([np.repeat(a[None,:], 5, axis=0) for a in arr if (a[1]==1 or a[1]==2)], axis=0)
Out[164]: 
array([[ 1,  2],
       [ 1,  2],
       [ 1,  2],
       [ 1,  2],
       [ 1,  2],
       [10,  1],
       [10,  1],
       [10,  1],
       [10,  1],
       [10,  1]])
```